# Reverse number in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, return

I have a homework to make a program that can reverse an input number, but have a requirement to return a sentence with no error when the input is not a number (i.e. words or sentence).
For example, when I input `abc` the program will return `Error, please input a number!`
How can I make it return a sentence when input a `str`
This is the code I've done so far.

```
def reverse_num(x):
    x = num
    x = str(x)
    
    if x[0] == '-':
        a = x[::-1]
        return f"{x[0]}{a[:-1]}"
    else:
        return x[::-1]

num = input("Enter an integer (positive or negative): ")
print (reverse_num(num))
```

Noted that the requirement is to reverse both positive and negative number with cannot be return `str`, but my code return all of them in reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's Break Your Problem in 2 Function:

A function to reverse and a loop to read until you get a number or user cancels:

```
    def reverse_input(num):
        if num[0] == "-":
            temp = num[:0:-1]
            return (-int(temp))
        return int(num[::-1])
    
    while True:
        num = input("Enter Number")
        if num[0] == "-":
            flag = num[1:].strip().isdigit()
        else:
            flag = num[:].strip().isdigit()
        if flag:
            print("User input is Number")
            print(reverse_input(num))
            break
        else:
            print("User input is string")
            resp = input("Would You like to try Again? Enter Y to try and N to Cancel")
            if resp == 'n' or resp == 'N':
                print("Sorry Execute Again")
```

What does it do ?

- It reads input from user. Input returns string always.
- First, we check if Entered String had negation sign or not. If it is there we'll test string skipping negation sign. Otherwise, we will use whole string.
- We will check if entered string is number using built-in isdigit() function. And Call function to get reversed string.
- Function will reverse string and typecast to integer with sign.